# Codeigniter customized user roles open specific pages only

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-roles

How do I define the user privileges in CI opening specific pages?
I was thinking  calling the database value every time open a page and see if he has any right to open the particular page. If he has no right it would show up, it would directly logged you out. But there would be so many pages to do.
I would create a function and check it everytime it open a page.
Is that the easiest way?

Thanks.

Comment: You could store the `USERS` roles on the session , then pass the roles on the function that will determine the users privilege . much better than accessing the users role on the database every time you want to check if he/she has rights to access.

Comment: @tomexsans Okay I got the part storing it in session. What about the page? The data that I would be saving is the current path file and the name of the rights. Also the level of users thats allowed. How do I link the database data with the user roles stored in session?

Comment: check zoe's answer. thats what i would do if i have already so many pages to check user roles/permissions on pages

Comment: @tomexsans I just checked it.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. You could query the database on every page load, that's fine, and ideal if the values are likely to change. Alternatively, you could save the privileges data into a session, and query the session on page load (similar to how you check if a user is already logged in).

> But there would be so many pages to do

You can extend the default CI_Controller and add your own code that runs on every page. For example, create a new file called `MY_Controller.php` in your `application/core/` directory, and put the code for your privileges check in the `__construct()` function, so runs automatically on every page load.

**application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Check privileges here. Something like..

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('privileges_model');

        $current_uri = uri_string(); 
            // If your url is something like http://some-site.com/blog/comments/123
            // this will return "/blog/comments/123"

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        if($this->privileges_model->check($user_id, $current_uri) == FALSE)
        {
            // The user DOES NOT have the correct permissions.
            // Log them out, redirect them somewhere else, etc etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controllers, instead of extending `CI_Controller`, you can extend your custom `MY_Controller`, inheriting its methods into every page.

**application/controllers/secret.php**

```
class Secret extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() 
    {
        // your secret page code here..
    }
}
```

This article by Phil Sturgeon goes into much more detail: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: Hi @zoe is the check privileges part  'declaring current user_roles'? If I store in my db, 'current path file, user roles, the rights name and id' how do I check the current path of the file matching the one in db?

Comment: @xyonme I've updated my answer to show how you might get the current path and send it to a privileges model. The privileges model is where you query your database and return the result (probably TRUE or FALSE), and either let the user proceed, or kick them out.

Comment: THANK you so much. I got the whole idea! ;)